# Javascript exercise

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do a javascript exercise where I have to create a random number between 0 and 100 the user has to guess, the program will have to warn if the generated number is higher or lower and must count the attempts made.
I leave below the code that works for me but the warning if the number is greater or less gives me all of them at the end and not one at a time and I can't count the attempts. Could anyone help me?

```js
var min=0; 
var max=10; 
var tent = 0;
var random =Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
document.write("Numero : " + random);
 

document.write("<br>");
for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    var input = prompt("Indovina il numero" );
    if (input < random){
       document.write("Il valore è più grande <br>");
        tent++;
    } else if (input > random) {
       document.write("Il valore è più piccolo <br>");
        tent++;
    } else {
       document.write("Hai indovinato");
        break;
    }
}
console.log( tent );
```

Comment: Please edit your code snippet because it pops up an alert without stopping.

Comment: You got bamboozled @iArcadia xD

Comment: Could you provide something like a current output and expected output? And please use englisch in your messages, they are not understandable as a non-(dont-know-the-language, spain?).

Comment: pressing cancel 10 times closes the dialog

Comment: It stops after 10 tries, rewarding persistent souls who are unafraid of being bamboozled.

Comment: I am Italian and I don't know English very well, to write the last comment I used google translator. The window closes after 10 times because according to the exercise there are only 10 attempts to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the text in your prompt and the count by doing this:

```js
var min=0; 
var max=10; 
var tent = 0;
var text = "";
var random =Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
document.write("Numero : " + random);
 

document.write("<br>");
for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    var input = prompt("Indovina il numero. " + text + " Attempts: " + i);
    if (input < random){
        text = "Il valore è più grande"
       document.write("Il valore è più grande <br>");
        tent++;
    } else if (input > random) {
         text = "Il valore è più piccolo"
       document.write("Il valore è più piccolo <br>");
        tent++;
    } else {
       document.write("Hai indovinato");
        break;
    }
}
console.log( tent );
```

The document won't write while the prompt is coming up. You should also handle cancelling to stop the loop instead of moving to the next and saying that your guess is too low.

Comment: thanks but i don't know how to manage the cancellation since it is the first time i use javascript

Comment: ok but you see in the window that opens if the value is too big or too small, that's fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a function for this...

```js
var maxTries=10; 
var tries = 0;

var min = 0
var max = 100;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 

 
function guess(){
  
  tries++;
  
  if(tries>maxTries){
   alert('You failed to guess the random number in '+maxTries+' tries!');
    return;
  }
  
  var input = prompt("Guess the random number:" );

  if(input>0){
  
  if(input==random){
   alert('Good job! You guessed the number in '+tries+' tries!');
  }else if(input<random){
   alert('Random number is larger than your guess...');
    guess();
  }else if(input>random){
    alert('Random number is smaller than your guess...');
    guess();
  }

  }
}

guess();
```